# Tooltip in svg a tag

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, svg

I am using svg tag inside my angular page ..

Below is the code for reference

`

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1"  x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 200 200" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 200;" xml:space="preserve" focusable="false">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .st1{fill:#3FA9F5;}
    .st2{font-family:'FontAwesome';}
    .st3{font-size:20px;}
</style>
<g>
<a class="pointer" href="#"  uib-tooltip ="Testing" tooltip-placement ="right" ng-click="doPTZOperation(0,1,2);$event.preventDefault();">
    <path class="st0" d="M122.3,44.7l15.5-36.8c-25-10.3-51.1-10-75.3-0.4l15,37.1C91.5,39.1,107.4,38.7,122.3,44.7z"/>
    <text transform="matrix(0.7404 -0.6722 0.6722 0.7404 98.521 31.4565)" class="st1 st2 st3" >ï„¤</text>
</a>
```

`

But,the tooltip is not working ...

Comment: Please provide more Information. Does your tooltip work if you don't use svg? What about console information?

Comment: Yes it works if I don't use the svg

Comment: What happens if you use `xlink:href="#"` instead of `href="#"` in your `a` tag?

Comment: I have changed href to xlink:href="#" But not make any sense

Comment: Does it work for you? Of course it make sense. Have a look at this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/xlink:href).

Comment: Yes It works..But tool-tip is still not working